# How to make sure that the destructor cannot throw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception-handling

I know that we can specify the compiler that a function is not throwing an exception by using noexcept specifier but noxecept functions can still throw exceptions . So, how to prevent destructor from throwing an exception ?

Comment: All I can say is code it properly. Do you have examples of code in which you believe the destructor could possibly throw an exception?

Comment: Do not use the `throw` keyword in your destructor, and catch exceptions that called functions throw? Not sure how to "guarantee" this, there are very few guarantees in programming.

Comment: I asked this question because I came across an exercise in c++ primer , which says that - "If you think one of your destructors might throw, change the code so that it cannot throw. "

Comment: How would a function marked `noexcept` still throw an exception? If a function marked `noexcept` throws an exception, the standard requires `std::terminate` to be called. `std::terminate`'s requirement is: "A terminate_handler shall terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a function is declared as `nothrow` throws an exception anyway, that is a bug pure and simple.

Given that, to ensure your destructors don't throw any exceptions, there are two paths:

1. Only call functions that are known not to throw an exception (either because they are declared with `nothrow`, they are documented not to throw, or they are implemented in a language without exceptions)
2. Wrap the calls in your destructor that could throw in a `try { } catch(...)` block.

Answer (score 2):

Just mark it `noexcept`.
In C++11 and following, your destructor is automatically declared `noexcept` unless at least one (base- or member-) subobject's destructor can throw, or you explicitly give a different exception-specification.

And if your function is marked non-throwing, it won't throw, ever, whatever you try.

Instead, it will:

1. If your exception-specification is dynamic (`throw()`), call [`std::unexpected()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected).
2. If your exception-specification is not dynamic, or `std::unexpected()` throws, call [`std::terminate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) to abort the program.